# Reference JSF control's attributes via JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, jsf

Is it possible to reference the `required` attribute of a JSF `h:inputText` control from JavaScript? This is a page that can't use AJAX and I'd like to set the `required` attribute based on the value in another text field.

Comment: Found a few articles: http://localhost:8080/request-forms/pages/overtime/overtime-n.seam and this: http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.com/2009/10/jsf-working-with-component-identifiers.html

Comment: the first link must a typo. It points to your localhost ;).

Comment: The second link is pretty good. Thanks for sharing it Alex.

Comment: Sorry for the first link; here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510831/how-to-reference-this-from-a-javascript-call-in-a-jsf-component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to set the required attribute based on the value in another text field.

Then just check *that* in the `required` attribute.

E.g. when you want to let it depend on whether the other field is filled in or not:

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input1}" binding="#{input1}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input2}" required="#{not empty input1.value}" />
```

Or when it has to be a specific value instead, e.g. "foo".

```
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input1}" binding="#{input1}" />
<h:inputText value="#{bean.input2}" required="#{input1.value == 'foo'}" />
```

Keep it simple.

Comment: Very nice, BalusC. Thank you -- exactly what I needed :)
 Simple and elegant too

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "access" JSF attributes from Javascript.  The attributes live on another machine to where the Javascript executes.

I think you can write the JSF to generate embedded Javascript that depends on JSF controls.  But I suspect that you will need to create and use your own JSF controls to make this happen.

(I'm generalizing from JSPs and JSTL ... but I think that the same principles apply.)

Comment: Thanks. Please see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to my knowledge. Java Script is executing on the client side, JSF controls are server side.

However, I think you can use ajax push and bind the required attributes value based on the value somebody types in a text field. Take a look at a framework like iceFaces that offers such functionality. But this is moving away from java script.