# JSF throws argument type mismatch when binding

Tags: java, jsf, binding, richfaces

I'm trying to do the following: When the user enters a value in the `rich:calendar` component, then the `h:inputText` should have its `required` attributed set to `true`. I'm following the instructions in this post: [Reference JSF control's attributes via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271794/reference-jsf-controls-attributes-via-javascript)

**Sorry** for creating another post, but I couldn't figure out how to post the code into the comments area and make it readable. The page throws this error:

`javax.el.ELException: /pages/overtime/overtime-n.xhtml @121,65 binding="#{oc.overtimeDate}": java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch`

The problem is that the binding is inside a `c:forEach` loop, and I'm trying to use the loop variable to bind to. The `overtime.overtimeItems` is defined as an `ArrayList<OvertimeComponent>` with each OvertimeComponent object having various properties (`overtimeDate`, `overtimeDateId`, `id`, `overtimeHours`, etc.).

```
<c:forEach items="#{overtime.overtimeItems}" var="oc">
  <rich:calendar value="#{oc.overtimeDate}" 
    requiredMessage="Date 1 is required."
    id="#{oc.overtimeDateId}" 
    binding="#{oc.overtimeDate}" 
    required="#{oc.id == 1 ? true : false}">
  </rich:calendar>
  <h:inputText value="#{oc.overtimeHours}" 
    id="#{oc.overtimeHoursId}"
    requiredMessage="Hours is required." 
    required="#{not empty oc.overtimeDate.value}" >
  </h:inputText>
  .....
</c:forEach>
```

How do I make the `h:inputText` required if the `rich:calendar` object has a value? There's a way to do this using the `binding` property of the calendar, but I'm not sure how to do it inside a `c:forEach`. I can't use AJAX for this project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `binding` attribute should point to an [`UIComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html), not to a value object like `Date`. The answer in your previous question would have worked if you wasn't using `c:forEach`.

```
<rich:calendar value="#{oc.overtimeDate}" 
    requiredMessage="Date 1 is required."
    id="#{oc.overtimeDateId}" 
    binding="#{calendarComponent}" 
    required="#{oc.id == 1 ? true : false}">
</rich:calendar>
<h:inputText value="#{oc.overtimeHours}" 
    id="#{oc.overtimeHoursId}"
    requiredMessage="Hours is required." 
    required="#{not empty calendarComponent.value}" >
</h:inputText>
```

The above example binds the component to the "page scope", not to a particular bean since you're usually not interested in the component from inside the bean. You can name `#{calendarComponent}` whatever you want. You can access it anywhere in the same page by the same name.

However, in your particular case you're using `c:forEach` and not `ui:repeat`, so components are actually repeated in the component tree (the `ui:repeat` only repeats in the HTML renderer). This means that you cannot use the suggested approach. All components would then share the same binding which is wrong. Best would be to add an `UIComponent` (more precise, [`UIInput`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html)) property to the object behind `oc` and bind to it instead, so that every component has its own unique binding. E.g.

```
public class OvertimeComponent {
    private UIInput calendarComponent;
    // ...
```

with

```
<rich:calendar value="#{oc.overtimeDate}" 
    requiredMessage="Date 1 is required."
    id="#{oc.overtimeDateId}" 
    binding="#{oc.calendarComponent}" 
    required="#{oc.id == 1}">
</rich:calendar>
<h:inputText value="#{oc.overtimeHours}" 
    id="#{oc.overtimeHoursId}"
    requiredMessage="Hours is required." 
    required="#{not empty oc.calendarComponent.value}" >
</h:inputText>
```

*(note that I simplified the EL of the `required` attribute of `rich:calendar` since it already returns a `boolean` anyway)*

Comment: Thanks, BalusC. I'm going to try this in the morning and let you know how it goes. I'm going to switch to ui:repeat. Didn't know the issues with the c:foreach. I might have a followup question. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks again, BalusC. I've implemented the change and it works! The trouble was that JBoss was somehow caching the old version and kept giving an error about not finding oc.calendarComponent on the OvertimeComponent class. I've run into this before and not sure why it does this. The only way to clear it out was to shut down Eclipse and restart. Annoying, but gets the job done.

Comment: By the way, I think this page is by you, BalusC: http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/communication-in-jsf.html Great resource for anyone wanting to learn JSF communication stuff. Excellent examples and highly recommended :) Thanks for creating that page. Keep up the great work.

Comment: Yes, it's me :) I must however admit that this article is outdated, considering that JSF 2.0 offers much more (and better and clean) ways to achieve the one and other.

Comment: Well, so many of us are still using JSF 1.x that the article is extremely useful :)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have both value and component binding on the calendar pointing to the same el expression ? You cannot do componentbinding on a richfaces calendar with type date.

Also, have you tried using ui:repeat instead of c:foreach ?

https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat

c:foreach is known to give problems in a facelets context related to the jsf and jsp lifecycle mismatch. Have a look at the post above for more info.

Comment: Thanks, ddewaele. I'm going to use ui:repeat instead of the c:foreach.